# PyCharm psycopg2 не работает автодополнение кода

Tags: python, pycharm, autocomplete, psycopg2

Всем привет. 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: после установки модуля psycopg2 PyCharm не хочет показывать подсказки (autocomplete) при написании кода для этого модуля. 
Для остальных модулей все работает хорошо.

Например, пытаюсь получить курсор к БД:

```
import psycopg2 as db
con = db.connect(con_string)
cur = con.cur (пусто при нажатии Ctrl + Space)
```

Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и решил ее, дайте, пожалуйста, совет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDE не знает возвращаемого типа `connect` (он не указан в докстроке, статически из кода его не вывести и аннотаций там тоже нет), поэтому не может ничего предложить. На это есть тикет в баг трекере PyCharm https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31565

В качестве обходного пути можно руками проаннотировать `con`, не уверен какой там конкретно тип используется, что-то подобное

```
from psycopg2._psycopg import connection
con: connection = db.connect(con_string)
```

После этого подсказки заработают. В идеальном мире кто-то должен написать stub-пакет для `psycopg2` с аннотациями типов доступного API.